# Wordpress Category Sidebar

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In the word press admin panel there is a category selection 'helper panel' which I am trying to recreate. However I can't find the code for it, could someone point me in the right direction please?

[image: Example]

Comment: Why are you trying to recreate it? How do you plan on using it? Where do you want to put it? Are you trying to create a Custom Taxonomy with a similar Hierarchical structure?

Comment: I need a layout similar which includes the check boxes, and yes follows the Hierarchical structure, I tried using the get_categories() function, but for some reason that was only returning categories which had a post count > 0 :S

Comment: Yes, but where do you feel it is missing? Did you add Custom Posts already? Or are you trying to add it somewhere else?

Comment: For a plugin I created I need a way to display all the categories in a Hierarchical table structure, with an additional column which has a input box. When the user inputs the desired value into the text box, it needs to save the value along with the category name, so that this data can be pulled and used in the front end of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual Category Box that is created by Wordpress is not typically used by Plugins that utilize a Custom UI. However, you can mimic its behavior, and you were most certainly on the right track with get_categories(). If you want to grab ALL categories, not just the ones with a post count, you need to call it like so:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'type'                     => 'post',
'orderby'                  => 'name',
'order'                    => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'               => 0, //<--IMPORTANT!!
'hierarchical'             => 1,
'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
'pad_counts'               => false );
$categories = get_categories($args);
?>
```

'hide_empty' is what you were missing. Once you want to create your checkboxes, you would do something like this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
<?php
foreach($categories as $cat)
{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="'.$cat->cat_ID.'" />';
    echo '<label>'$cat->name.'</label><br/>';
}
?>
<input type="text" name="user_input" value="" />
</form>
```

You can style the checkboxes however you like using a [custom stylesheet](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts), or you can apply the same  tags and classes that the standard one uses, which will ensure that the existing Wordpress Admin Stylesheet styles everything accordingly.

Comment: As mentioned, you were on the right track. Read more about get_categories here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories